# WordPress function to show content

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I'm in need of a function to check content from a certain part of the site and print it on the main header.
Any idea of how can i do this? It's a radio website.
What i need to track is the content of each program and print the names on the header every half hour.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you already tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Been thinking of using hooks.